# PiVPN on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS x86_64

Tags: networking, openvpn

So, I'm trying to follow the easiest setup for OpenVPN on my VPS. I tried installing it manually, it worked and my client could connect but no internet worked. I'm in China anyway so when I saw a guide on installing with Obfsproxy I thought why not it seems easy.

Anyway, I get to installed pivpn (I know it's for Pi but it's just an installer for OpenVPN) and when it comes to selecting my IP I get:

```
: error fetching interface information: Device not found
: error fetching interface information: Device not found
```

So I tried running lspci and that also doesn't work. Here is my output from ifconfig -a and maybe explains why OpenVPN didn't work in the first place? There's no eth0?

```
lo Link encap:Local Loopback
inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0
inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:65536 Metric:1
RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
RX bytes:0 (0.0 B) TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)


venet0 Link encap:UNSPEC HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
inet addr:127.0.0.2 P-t-P:127.0.0.2 Bcast:0.0.0.0 Mask:255.255.255.255
inet6 addr: 2a04:ad80:1:110::d453/64 Scope:Global
UP BROADCAST POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MTU:1500 Metric:1
RX packets:130535 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:11783 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
RX bytes:190830531 (190.8 MB) TX bytes:1421725 (1.4 MB)


venet0:0 Link encap:UNSPEC HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
inet addr:176.126.245.30 P-t-P:176.126.245.30 Bcast:176.126.245.30 Mask:255.255.255.255
UP BROADCAST POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MTU:1500 Metric:1
```

Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

- I have a VM (running Ubuntu 16.04) in Hongkong and installed PiVPN and OpenVPN, by following the instruction at https://github.com/pivpn/pivpn.
- The setup script `curl -L https://install.pivpn.io | bash` allows you specify lots of things, such as public IP, interface, tls-crypt (Obfsproxy), very straightforward
- To find out your device, run

  `ip link
  ip address`
- If you still can't get your OpenVPN working, after successfully connected, check your DNS

Hope this helps